# Return false from method to main arg

Tags: methods, boolean

I can't seem to get the method to return false and give the statement "The product was not found." if I enter a product not in the catalog. It automatically returns true for any product whether its in the catalog or not. I only posted the method that this deals with and the main argument because it wouldn't let me post such a long program. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static boolean getOrder(String productsCatalog){
    System.out.print("Enter the product name: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String product = in.next();
    if (productsCatalog.contains(product)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    bannerPrinter();
    String productsCatalog = productsBuilder();
    boolean productAvailable = getOrder(productsCatalog);
    if (productAvailable == true){
        double price = getPrice();
        double tax = getTax(price);
        double saleTotal = getTotal(price, tax);
        printTotal(saleTotal);
    }
    else if (productAvailable == false) {
        System.out.println("The product was not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to compare a value to true.  You also don't add the false comparison in the else clause.  It should be simply: `if (productAvailable) {...} else {...}`
Based on your code, `productsCatalog.contains(product)` is returning an incorrect value.

Comment: Okay thank you. I took out the comparisons but I'm still having trouble with the productsCatalog.contains(product). I must not be storing the string of items correctly?

    public static String productsBuilder(){
    String productsCatalog = "Pencil    " + "Calculator" + "Textbook  ";
    return productsCatalog;
    }